# What is the code Wordpress uses to make SEO friendly URLs?

Tags: regex, wordpress

Can anyone point me to the standard code Wordpress uses to turn a blog post url from this:

```
http://myblog.com/?p=123
```

into this:

```
http://myblog.com/this-is-my-articles-title-i-think
```

If the post title was: This Is My Article's "Title" (I Think)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress doesn't redirect or rewrite requests. `index.php` serves the content based on the original request URI. It catches requests that don't exist and figures them out from the plug. This code is in the WordPress document root in `.htaccess`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /wordpress/  
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]  
</IfModule>
```

If you want to know how WP generates the permalink *slugs*, look in `wp-includes/formatting.php` for this function:

```
function sanitize_title_with_dashes($title) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your wordpress admin go to settings > permalinks and select 'post name' then save changes and you're all set.